# Why am I getting a UserName Error when running DIFF command in liquibase?

Tags: liquibase

Trying to run a Diff command, I am fairly certain my command is correct however every time I run I get a "--userName=Root: command not found" error.  And nothing executes.  See command and results below.  Any thoughts as too why?  Please note I've added the line breaks in my command line for ease of reading, when I enter the command it is all on one line.

```
liquibase 
--driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver 
--url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/dev?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC 
--userName=root 
--password=SomePassword 
--logLevel=debug diff 
--referenceUrl=jdbc:mysql://localhost/Prod?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC 
--referenceUsername=root 
--referencePassword=SomePassword
[1] 5437
[2] 5438
[3] 5439
[4] 5440
[5] 5441
[6] 5442
-bash: --userName=root: command not found
-bash: --referenceUsername=root: command not found
[2]   Done                    useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true
[3]   Done                    useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
[5]-  Done                    useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true
[6]+  Done                    useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
[4]+  Exit 127                serverTimezone=UTC --userName=root --password=SomePassword --logLevel=debug diff --referenceUrl=jdbc:mysql://localhost/Prod?useUnicode=true
macbook:~ name$ Starting Liquibase at Wed, 26 Jun 2019 07:22:10 CDT (version 3.6.3 built at 2019-01-29 11:34:48)
Errors:
  No command was passed.
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect a bash parsing error. Try enclosing either the urls in quotes or the whole `--url=<connectstring>` argument in quotes.

Another option is to put the parameters into a `liquibase.properties` file so you don't have to specify them on the command line. You can even set up different properties files and specify `--defaultsFile=</path/to/file>` to use different files for different environments. If you don't specify that option, liquibase will look for a file named `liquibase.properties`